# How is the seed for choosing proposers calculated if RANDAO fails to produce new randomness?

Tags: proof-of-stake, randomness

I understand that RANDAO can fail to produce new randomness if one of the participants doesn't submit their secret. What are the exact mechanics of such situation?

Some more details that would be helpful that I couldn't find answers to:

- How much stake secures the submission of secrets? Is it burned or redistributed?
- How often is new randomness computed? Once per epoch?
- How many users usually participate in RANDAO?
- Does the ethereum protocol pay RANDAO for providing this service? How much? Does it access it through smart contract calls or just read the value?

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide short answers to your questions and give you a link for a more thorough explanation.

---

> I understand that RANDAO can fail to produce new randomness if one of the participants doesn't submit their secret

That's not the case! RANDAO works fine even if one or more participants don't submit their contribution for randomness.

> How much stake secures the submission of secrets? Is it burned or redistributed?

I'm not sure I understand the question. To submit his randomness, a participant needs to be a block-proposer. To be a block-proposer, you have to be a validator. And to be a validator, you need to stake ETH.
But there is no stake 'directly' involved in participating in RANDAO.

> How often is new randomness computed? Once per epoch?

Yes, at the end of each epoch, we take all the randomness produced by block proposer to create a seed.

[image]

> How many users usually participate in RANDAO?

Usually 32. All the proposers of the epoch.

> Does the ethereum protocol pay RANDAO for providing this service? How much? Does it access it through smart contract calls or just read the value?

I think there is some confusion here, but it's a comprehensive one. RANDAO is both the name of an organization (DAO) and the mechanism they use. Ethereum uses the same mechanism but not the DAO in itself.

Here is a link to dive deeper into what RANDAO is and how it's used in Ethereum: https://nodeguardians.io/dev-hub/quests/consensus-randao.